# Computer making ticking sounds, windows 8.1 crashing, continuous buzzer sounds

Tags: windows, hard-drive, noise

I have a problem that I can't get rid off. This morning I've turned on computer, didn't pay attention if the splash screen of motherboard is on the screen.

Computer started to have a black screen and produce a series of 'tick' sounds (just like when you hit the 'restart' button, it makes that tiny mechanical tick), a windows 8.1 loading screen occurred and a couple of ticks happened again.

Then suddenly all computer shut down. No reboot, no crash report, no anything, just straight to shutdown. I stood all stunned looking at my PC and the screen. I decided to boot it once again. Again the same old tick sounds 'fired' up in a machine gun fashion.

This time, however, the system booted to the user screen where a user needs to input their password to access the desktop. I was surprised in seeing that the password field was already filled with two lines of characters (dunno which ones exactly as they are represented as dots for security reasons).

When I've entered the password, I failed to log in a couple of times (I noticed later that sometimes upon writing, computer decides to duplicate character a couple of times which probably caused issues with logging in). After I logged in, windows informed me that computer had a serious crash and asked me to send two system files to Microsoft. I agreed.

I've noticed that 1 number doesn't work unless Num Lock is pressed as well as A letter doesn't work unless Caps Lock is turned on or left Shift button is pressed instead of right one. Other characters seem to work fine. In general, there's no performance drop upon logging in.

I also noticed that sometimes the hard drive 'thinks' for a really long time(for example if I'm switching/closing single tabs in Google Chrome browser). Also, once today my computer went into sleep mode and upon waking up I couldn't go to the tiles screen. Clicking on windows icon in left down corner didn't work.

Here's the decoded minidump file decoded that I took from the Windows folder:

Here it is decoded:

```
Instant Online Crash Analysis, brought to you by OSR Open Systems Resources, Inc.

Show DivPrimary Analysis

Crash Dump Analysis provided by OSR Open Systems Resources, Inc. (http://www.osr.com)
Online Crash Dump Analysis Service
See http://www.osronline.com for more information
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9600 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 9600.17041.amd64fre.winblue_gdr.140305-1710
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff803`4b280000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff803`4b54a2d0
Debug session time: Mon May 19 21:50:24.828 2014 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 14:41:46.524
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

HAL_INITIALIZATION_FAILED (5c)
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000002001
Arg2: 0000000000000003
Arg3: 0000000000000004
Arg4: ffffffffffd01398

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x5C

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8034b268eab to fffff8034b3d3fa0

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
hal!HalpInterruptReinitialize+0x2d0f
hal!HalpAcpiPostSleep+0x136
hal!HaliAcpiSleep+0x2ba
nt!PopHandleNextState+0x128
nt!PopIssueNextState+0x1f
nt!PopInvokeSystemStateHandler+0x2a1
nt!PopEndMirroring+0xd2
nt!MmDuplicateMemory+0x7c1
nt!PopTransitionToSleep+0x103
nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x58
nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!PopHandleNextState+128
fffff803`4b5e935c 8be8            mov     ebp,eax

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PopHandleNextState+128

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5318053f

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x5C_HAL_FAILED_TO_RESTART_PROCESSOR_AFTER_SLEEP_nt!PopHandleNextState+128

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x5C_HAL_FAILED_TO_RESTART_PROCESSOR_AFTER_SLEEP_nt!PopHandleNextState+128

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

This free analysis is provided by OSR Open Systems Resources, Inc.
Want a deeper understanding of crash dump analysis? Check out our Windows Kernel Debugging and Crash Dump Analysis Seminar (opens in new tab/window)
Show DivCrash Code Links

Show DivLoaded Module List

Show DivRaw Stack Contents

Show DivDump Header Information

Show DivStrings
```

The problem still occurs each time I reboot computer or perform a 'cold start'. Also, rebooting takes longer than before. Yesterday it ran like a rocket, without any problems.

What I've tested:

1. HDD's with HD Tune utility. The system drive, which is a 120 GB Samsung SSD, and the secondary drive, which is 320 GB Seagate Barracuda from 2007, both had no bad sectors.
2. I've checked the tip to disable 'quick booting' in Windows 8.1 under Control Panel and Power Options. Didn't help at all.
3. Checked the language options. The keyboard main language is correct and the main environment language is also correct.
4. I've checked computer with Avira Antivirus Personal free edition. Checked for rootkits as well. No detection. Have run it in normal mode, not safe mode. While scanning, from time to time, I had a strange message from the OS saying:

> Bin on disk C is damaged, do you want to empty the bin on this drive?

Update:

Here's the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6kcr6UNJM4&list=PL1ZUL5eWv7V_o01ToMUOanCj1YIQ7vWA_&feature=mh_lolz) to the Video Playlist showing the previous and present state of the problem:

Today I've decided to check if the ticking noise will occur in situation in which I would  remove the second hard drive (the one filled only with data) and leave the SSD with OS on it.

This is what happened when I have unplugged second hard drive (mechanical one just for data) and left first one (SSD with legal windows 8.1) inside computer:

Continuous beeping sound suggests RAM issues ? Double checked if Geil Dragon 2x4GB RAM's are not unseated and even took out one stick. Still without any change. Taking out both of them and turning on computer results with dark screen, continuous short beep sounds (like a bomb) and restart loops each 10 seconds (approximately).

Having both HDD's plugged, computer is still making continous  beeping noise from buzzer as well as delicate clicks (barely heard cause of buzzer). It tries to boot into windows 8.1 login screen but fails terribly. Blue Screen of Death appears, data about the critical event is being slowly collected and the error status is 0xc000021a. Seems like corrupted winlogon.exe or winload.exe files. However, nothing is sure for me on this stage of investigation.

Synopsis:

Computer randomly restarted

Noticed multiple irregular ticking noises (same tick as when you push once the restart button)

Noticed irregular ticking noises each time I'm turning on my computer

Noticed Windows bugs such as capitalized 'A' letter not working (occurs only when right shift is pressed, with left one it works well) and key with '1' number not working

Have been instructed elsewhere to replace the secondary hard drive with new one. Bought Kingston KC 300 240 GB Sata III SSD drive.

Before I tried anything else I performed a backup of my data.  Before mounting new hard drive, I've decided to check how computer will act when unplugging secondary hard drive (the one to serve a purpose to be just a storage drive, not OS drive)

Booted computer with only SSD OS drive plugged.

Noticed long infinite continuous buzzer beep sound and Windows having problems to boot (displaying error status 0xc000021a alternately with 0xc0000001). It never succeeded to fully boot to login screen.

Read the manual for the motherboard on internet. Decided to uninstall, first Slot 1, then Slot 2, of the Geil Dragon 4gb RAM modules. Upon unmounting first stick - no change. Upon unmounting both of them - short continuous infinite beep sounds, black screen, restart loop each 10 seconds.

Tried to plug both hard drives back again. Computer still having problems to boot, displaying error statuses 0xc000021a alternately with 0xc0000001 (last one happens rarely).

Decided to unmount both hard drives. Upon unmounting, the buzzer was still making continuous infinite sound.

Ran out of ideas.

Computer specification:

1. Mobo: Gigabyte H61M-S2V-B3
2. CPU: Intel Core i3 2125 Sandy Bridge 1155 LGA
3. Ram: 8 GB DDR3 Dual Channel of Dragon memory
4. HDD Primary: Samsung SSD 120 GB
5. HDD Secondary: Seagate Barracuda 320 GB
6. OS: Legal Copy of Microsoft Windows 8.1, all minor and major updates downloaded and installed.

I welcome any help on the cause of this problem as well any possible solution.

Comment: No Windows 8.1 isn't the cause

Comment: So what can be ? Before I used to have problems with audio turning off completely in random moments when a lot of google chrome tabs were opened. As soon as the process of chrome was killed, the sound was coming back.

Comment: Does the sound come from your speakers or your hdd?  Use BlueScreenViewer to see what drivers were loaded when the computer crashed and update your question

Comment: Sound comes from a tiny tactile switch. It's a mechanical sound, from inside the computer. The same sound normally occurs a half of a second upon hitting the 'reset' button, except that it's like if someone would shoot a machine gun with some pauses. This never happened before.

Comment: That sound isn't caused by software if it's a mechanical sound

Comment: But nothing was changed since yesterday. Computer is at the same place as before, dust free, well taken care of. Temperatures are fine and I'm sure nothing is in the fans. So what is causing these anomalies then. Why this ticking sound, weird things in windows 8.1 and some random keys not working ? All this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Hardware can fail without a reason.  I had hardware that was working one day, 3 weeks later with it unplugged, I turn it on and it doesn't work.  You recycle bin is damage, that indicates file system problems, which indicates hdd problems.

Comment: Hints :) I like that. Ok, HDD hummm. I'll go deeper then and ask : are bad sectors the only determinant of a damaged HDD ?

Oh yes...and why there was this message about "DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT" in the decoded .dmp file ?

Comment: HDDs are mechanical.  So two types of failures can happen.  You can get a mechanical failure ( grinding noise ) or sectors on the disk can fail.  When this happens the drive is unable to perform error correction and/or spends all its times attempting to do ( more so the OS attempts to read a file on a bad sector but can't ).  There are other types of failures similar to both some are detected by the drive itself ( and would indicated by the S.M.A.R.T data ).  Just because there are not bad sectors does not mean there are not other problems with the drive. Good Drives = Good File System.

Comment: I need to exclude the HDD as a main cause in here. There's no unusual noise coming out from it. And about bad sectors, I've checked the HDD with HD tune. No bad sectors at all so it has to be something else.

Comment: The only application I use to diagnose BSOD problems is `BlueScreenViewer` because it tells you what drivers were loaded.  At the end of the day your recycle bin was "damaged" which indicates a file system problem which is very unlikely on a drive that is actually working to specifications. I am having problems understanding what actual piece of hardware generates the sound.

Comment: Here's the link to the vid showing the ticking noise. The vid takes place just upon clicking the power button:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l10wqwg96vkn286/WP_20140520_005.mp4

Comment: Your HDD is making those noises.  I hear a scratching sound and what I would called actually perhaps called strained HDD activity.

Comment: I saw a couple of vids on youtube with 'hdd clicking' in the title. Here it's quite different. It's more like this one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPXAhfwKa3Q

What I don't understand still is why capital 'a' letter doesn't work or 'one' character as well. The system is on a healthy SSD from Samsung.

Comment: You asked what it could be.  I have provided my take on your problem.  I have see hundreds of problems and eventually solved most of them some of my own problems most other peoples.

Comment: The BSOD is from you turning your computer on then turning it off without a proper shutdown more then likely.  Try joining this [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14900/danny-student)

Comment: Thanks for answer ! There was no possibility to shut it down the healthy way. The only way was to press power button and hold it for 5 seconds. BSOD is appearing each time when booting up with either one or both HDD's plugged in.

Comment: I also don't see where you replaced the only mechanical drive you have, the actually HDD, the SSD does not have the ability to make "ticking" noises it has no mechanical parts.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just a second ago I've checked all the fans (especially the one on CPU), they rotate freely, there's no bearing noise, they are quite new as well. I can reinstall windows without any problems. The thing is that most likely I'll hear the constant beep sound all the time (as it begins at the time when mobo splash screen pops up). This would indicate that something else is also wrong independently to the system issues.

P.s. I didn't replace yet the mechanical drive with newly bought secondary SSD (kingston 240 gb), I was concerned about the sounds coming from buzzer.

Comment: Well....You tried to boot the system without any memory installed which you can't do.  Of course the system went into an infinite loop you had zero memory modules installed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that part. I actually thought that it can boot up at least to bios without any RAMs installed. This case is a riddle, just like everything in life. Problems occur especially when they are the least expected. Any further tips would be greatly apprecieated :)

Comment: What I should do now in order to make my computer fully usable ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds distinctly like a hardware problem. This is going to be a "process of elimination" problem. You'll need to start disconnecting things one at a time. You may also need to dig up spare parts to test, just in case. Also try re-seating things, like PCI cards and RAM.

Sudden crashes with no BSOD are usually strong indicators of bad power regulation. This can happen due to a dying power supply or a motherboard going bad. But it could also be system overheating. (If you're in the northern hemisphere, it's turning into summertime and interior house temperatures are going up, which makes your PC run warmer.)

Heck, check your SATA cables, too. A friend of mine recently had problems with his PC starting up. He went into start unplugging things and the SATA connector broke off in his hand. He went out and got new SATA cables and all the problems evaporated.

Good luck.

EDIT:  My next suggestion would be to update any firmware that you can: Motherboard and SSD are good candidates.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! There are no extension cards installed currently in my PC. I'm using integrated graphics (the ones that come with intel core i3 CPU). RAM was already removed (first one stick then both at a time). Upon removing one RAM stick it made no difference (still constant beeping sounds from buzzer). Upon removing both sticks, computer had all the time black screen and continued to re-boot automatically each 10 seconds. PSU is quite young (aroung 4 months) and was picked up carefully (corsair). Overheating would be the cause but it was cold recently at my place (last 3 weeks).

Comment: When it comes to mobo, all transistors and resistors look healthy and not swollen/blown. SATA cables checked twice, replugged, no difference. Connectors are not broken and well plugged to the drives. All these issues appeared suddenly. What I especially don't understand is why computer didn't want to boot when I've unplugged the second HDD used only for storage. My system is on SSD drive which was plugged in but system couldn't boot up cause winloader.exe is missing ? That's really confusing and out of logic...

Comment: Any additional advices ? :)

Comment: Have you tried updating any firmware yet?  (Motherboard or SSD)

Comment: No I haven't tried. However, today I've bought a new good quality casing for my computer because I thought that the power button or reset button may have had some sort of a short circuit problems. The case is by Logic model B38. I've patiently and delicately reseated all of the components and upon powering up my computer and plugging bootable usb with a legal image of windows 8.1 it again started to generate the same clicking noise. I've restarted the computer and one click occured, then again the same story. I have no idea what can it be. I've uploaded new vid :

http://youtu.be/Bjnkv9DYcL4